# Unzip speed is too slow

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am using react-native-zip-archive for unzip my file.

Here's my source code.

```
            unzip(res.path(), targetPath)
              .then((path) => {
                RNFS.unlink(res.path())
                  .then(() => {
                    console.log('FILE DELETED');
                  })
                  // `unlink` will throw an error, if the item to unlink does not exist
                  .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err.message);
                  });
              })
              .catch((error) => {
              });
```

Zip file is 235MB. And extracting it takes around 30min.
Is there anyway to improve extracting speed?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I would suggest you also add the use case to your question, so that if there is an alternate solution for your situation, people can suggest that

Comment: You should provide more details about your case: what is unzipped file size, what iOS version you use, what is react-native-zip-archive version?

Comment: ios version 11 and react-native-zip-archive version is 2.0. And could you tell me about normal speed?

Comment: are you measuring on an actual device or in an emulator?

Comment: actual device but not working on simulator

Comment: How many files do you have? One of the implementation I used in the past was performing the search using a O(N) algorithm. Maybe that's the root cause (given an enough big N)

Comment: @StefanoBuora If I understand the code correctly, the code does not search, it just unzips the whole archive into a folder and then it deletes the archive.

Comment: @Sulthan I believe you're right. Still wonder if the number of element in the zip archive matters....

Comment: Yeah, if the compression ratio us high, the result could be in gigabytes. Hard to say without checking the file. Encryption and compression level would also affect the speed a lot.

Comment: Actually, elements in the zip file is too much. It will be more than 50000 items.

Comment: "If I understand the code correctly, the code does not search, it just unzips the whole archive into a folder and then it deletes the archive" ----Can I get the detailed info about this?

Comment: Although the elements are more than 50000, the speed can't exceed about 15 minutes. I think there's a suitable method and I will be back with a perfect answer. I think big N is the solution at the moment. It will take a lot of memory but also can be fasten the speed. :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest u use this zip library.This is useful and well compressed
[pako](https://github.com/nodeca/pako)